# How to create rebar.config file Erlang

Tags: erlang, rebar

I want to add dependencies in erlang project through rebar. Do I need to create manually or is there any rebar command to create rebar.config file. Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using rebar3, the example the docs show already generates the rebar.config file:

```
rebar3 new release myrelease
```

And it generates:

```
===> Writing apps/myrelease/src/myrelease_app.erl
===> Writing apps/myrelease/src/myrelease_sup.erl
===> Writing apps/myrelease/src/myrelease.app.src
===> Writing rebar.config
===> Writing config/sys.config
===> Writing config/vm.args
===> Writing .gitignore
===> Writing LICENSE
===> Writing README.md
```

Comment: thanks for the reply! Actually, i wanted to add a library in my project that too before release!! So I created rebar.config manually & added required code, dependencies in it. I doubt its correct way, still learning ;)

Comment: Thanks, @Asier :)